# Java exception error after exporting javafx jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have a javafx application that I've been developing in eclipse and it is working fine on the IDE. However, when I export it into a jar, I get the following Exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.application.Application
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 13 more
Exception in thread "main"
```

I've even created a MainTerminal class that doesn't use javaFX, instead just interacts within the terminal and after I exported the jar using MainTerminal as the main class and it worked fine. It seems I'm not being able to export some dependency or something but I checked the buildpath and it seemed alright to me.

Comment: What language level do you use at compile time?

Comment: At eclipse project properties, I set "JDK Compliance" to "Use  compliance from execution environment 'JavaSE-1.7' on the 'Java Build Path'", since I have jdk8 installed but want to run my application on a java7 environment.

Comment: Could you set it to Java 1.8 for testing purposes and package & run it again?

Comment: I checked the exported classes and they're all version 51.0 which is java7 if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Ok, @MrPixelDream I'll try it out.

Comment: Thanks for the fast support @MrPixelDream ! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel quite dumb about this but I just found out what my problem was. **I was exporting my project as a Jar instead of a runnable Jar**, that's why it was throwing an exception when I tried executing it.